# Finding all positive integers $x,y,z$ that satisfy $3^x - 5^y = z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, contest-math

> Find all positive integers $x,y,z$ that satisfy:
>
> $$3^x - 5^y = z^2.$$

I think that $(x,y,z)= (2,1,2)$ will be the only solution. But how to prove that?

Comment: For any (contest-math) question, there should be the source of the problem in the body of the question.

Comment: any one..???????????????????????

Answer (score 7):

Notice that:

$$\begin{align}3^x - 5^y &\equiv (-1)^{x} - 1 \mod 4\\
z^2 &\equiv  (-1)^x - 1 \mod{4}\\
&\equiv \begin{cases} 0 & \text{$x$ even,}\\ 2 & \text{$x$ odd}\end{cases} \end{align}$$

Since $2$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $4$, $x$ must be even $\implies x = 2a$ for positive integer $a$. Furthermore, $4| z^2 \implies 2|z \implies z = 2b$ for positive integer b.

Hence, we get:
$$\begin{align}3^{2a} - 5^y &= (2b)^2\\
5^y &= 3^{2a} - (2b)^2\\
5^y &= (3^a + 2b)(3^a - 2b)\end{align}$$

If $(3^a - 2b) > 1$, we notice that :
$$\begin{align}
&a,b > 0, a \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\implies &3^a + 2b > 3^a - 2b \ge 1\\
\implies &3^a + 2b > 1\end{align}$$

But $3^a + 2b$ is a perfect power of 5, implying that $5|(3^a + 2b)$. Hence, we have :

$$\begin{align}
3^a + 2b &\equiv 0 \mod 5\\
3^a - 2b &\equiv -4b \mod 5\\
3^a - 2b &\equiv b \mod 5\end{align}$$

If $(3^a - 2b)$ is a perfect power of $5$ (excluding 1), then from above, we get $b = 5k$ for positive integer $k$. But if $b = 5k$, then:
$$\begin{align}3^a + 2b &= 3^a + 10k\\
&\equiv 3^a \mod {5}\\
&\not\equiv 0 \mod{5}\end{align}$$

Hence, $(3^a - 2b)$ cannot be greater than $1$ $\implies 3^{\frac{x}{2}} - z = 1 \implies 3^x = (1 + z)^2$, which has infinitely many solutions, one of which is $x = 2, z = 2 \implies y = 1$. Now, we just have to find a way to show that there are no other solutions.

Comment: i am left with and equation $2.3^n=5^4$$^k$$+^1$  + $1 $

Comment: plz give the full solution...

Comment: ????????????????????

Comment: @mathslover Sorry for the late reply, was away. I've updated my answer to give the full solution.

Comment: how did u deduce that $(z + 1)^2 = 3^x$. has only one solution..>?

Comment: @mathslover It seems like I was indeed unable to deduce from that alone. Seems like I'll have to turn this answer into a partial one (for now).

Comment: i know ..i was stuck here only.!!

Comment: ?????????????????????????????????/

Answer (score 2):

I will give a brief review to Yiyuan's answer, and then complete the proof. We have:
$$3^x-5^y=z^2$$
Working $\pmod4$, we have $(-1)^x-1\equiv 0,1 \pmod4$, so $x$ has to be even. Substituting $x=2k$ and $y=a+b$:
$$(3^k-z)(3^k+z)=5^y\implies 3^k-z=5^a, 3^k+z=5^b\implies 2\times3^k=5^a+5^b$$

If $a,b\ge1$, then the RHS is a multiple of $5$ but the LHS is not, so WLOG assume $b=0$. Then:
$$2\times3^k=1+5^a$$
There is no solutions with $k=0$ and one with $k=1(x=2,y=1,z=2)$. Assume henceforth that $k\ge 2$.  We then have $-1\equiv 5^a \pmod9$, and since $a=3$ is the smallest solution, we can easily see that every solution is of the form $a=6m+3=3(2m+1)$. Finally
$$2\times3^k=1+5^{3(2m+1)}=(1+5^3)(\cdots)=126(\cdots)$$
But now the RHS is a multiple of $7$. Therefore the only solution is $(x=2,y=1,z=2)$.