# Solving for $3^x - 1 = 2^y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, congruences

Besides $x=2, y=3$, are there any other solutions?

I know that if there is another solution:

- $y$ is odd since $2^y \equiv -1 \pmod 3$
- $x$ is even since $3^x - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$
- $3 | y$ since $-1 \equiv 2^y \pmod 9$

Are there any other solutions?  If not, what is the argument for showing that if $3^x > 9$, then $2^y \neq 3^x-1$

Thanks,

-Larry

Comment: @GottfriedHelms:  Did you mean [Gersonides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#History)?

Comment: You do not need Catalan - this is so simple (see @Dan's answer) that even the medieval mathematician Gersonides has found it (due to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#History ) (Note: here I corrected my earlier wrong comment thanks to intervention of @J.W.Tanner)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the full strength of Catalan's conjecture here.

Two solutions are found easily. $3^1-1=2^1$ gives $x=y=1$. $3^2-1=2^3$ gives $x=2$ and $y=3$.

To prove that these are the only solutions, assume $x > 2$. As you have noted, $x$ must be even: $x = 2z$. Now we have
$$
3^x-1 = 3^{2z}-1 = (3^z-1)(3^z+1) = 2^y.
$$
It follows that both $3^z-1$ and $3^z+1$ are powers of $2$. But this is impossible, because both numbers are larger than $2$ (since $z > 1$), and they are only two units apart. QED.

PS: I think I've seen this argument somewhere on math.SE.

Comment: I believe the mentioned argument is somewhat similar to the second last paragraph of Barry Cipra's solution to this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662121/the-equation-3n4m-5k-in-positive-integer-numbers

Answer (score 1):

[Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (now a theorem, with the alternative name "Mihăilescu's theorem") asserts that there are no other possible solutions to the diophantine equation in integers $a,x,b,y > 1$:

$$a^x - b^y = 1$$

other than the solution $(a,b,x,y) = (3,2,2,3)$. As for the proof, I believe that Mihailescu's original proof is not simple enough to be placed into a single answer. Here is a link to a simpler and more elementary one, though it is still considerably long: [Elementary proof of Mihailescu's Theorem](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=proof%20of%20catalan-mihailescu%20theorem&oq=proof%20of%20mihail&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.3009j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'll look for the proof behind Catalan's conjecture.

Comment: It'll be difficult to find an elementary proof, I guess there is none until so far.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://rxiv.org/pdf/1109.0054v2.pdf) can help you to get an answer to your question.