# Solve over positive integers: $1+4^x=5^y$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Find all solutions to $1+4^\mathcal{x}=5^{\mathcal{y}}$ given that $x,y \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

Do give a proof.
Some calculus proof will be better. Non-calculus will also be okay. But since I am learning calculus, I would like that more.. 
I got no idea using calculus to be true..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mathmo123 that is not true! For example, the infinitude of the primes can be proved directly from divergence of the harmonic series, and the whole subject of analytic number theory developed out of using ideas from calculus (and analysis) to prove properties of integers.

Comment: @KCd You are of course correct. My intention was more along the lines of the kind of calculus that would usually go along with the tags (algebra-precalculus) and the description "calculus proof" probably won't help - i.e. you can't expect to be able to differentiate the equation. Admittedly, my phrasing was poor.

Comment: The more general $3^x+4^y=5^z$ is a classic: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662121

Answer (score 5):

Hints: Suppose $x>1$. Looking modulo $8$, note that $y$ must be even, say $y=2k$. Then $4^x=5^y-1=(5^k+1)(5^k-1)$. Now look at prime factorizations.

Answer (score 4):

An elementary proof. You have
$$
5^{y} - 1 = (5 - 1) (1 + 5 + \dots + 5^{y-1}),
$$
so
$$
4^{x-1} =  1 + 5 + 5^{2} + \dots + 5^{y-1}.
$$
If $x > 1$, RHS is divisible by $4$. Since $5 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, we have that $y$ is divisible by $4$.

But then $5^{y} - 1$ is divisible by $5^{4} - 1 = 624$, which is not a power of $2$. (Thanks to @Wojowu for the correction.)

Comment: What's important is that $624$ is not a power of $2$. After all, $4^2$ is still divisible by $8$.

Comment: @Wojowu, quite right, I will fix, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an obvious solution: $x=y=1$. [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture) (aka Mihailescu's theorem) states that there is no more.

Comment: Whenever one invokes Catalan's conjecture, it is worth pointing out it's not just a conjecture anymore.

Answer (score 1):

One might note, by the application of fermat's little theorm, applied to integers, that the period of $2^n$ in base 5, has a period of $2^{(n-2)}$.  This means that that the first power of 5 that is one more than a multiple of 16 is $5^4-1$, but this is the product of the double-even $5^2-1$ and the double-odd $5^2+1$.  Since every power of $5^n-1$ that 16 divides, so does 13, the only example of $5^a=4^b+1$ is for $a=b=1$.